# how to use table adapter query for search with possibility of empty string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-code

I have a gridview linked with the object data source. The Object data source is linked with a table adapter query which has a search term. Now the issue is that initially there is no value and when there is no value with table adapter query returns no row.

So is there a way to have a table adapter query which returns all the rows when there is no input value.

The current table adapter query is.

```
SELECT personid, name, departmentName, email 
FROM dbo.vwAdminView
where name like '%'+@searchTerm+'%' or email like '%'+@searchTerm+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are actually quite a few ways to do this.

but, when you build the SQL, and build/set the parameter's?

They can be build 100% independent of each other. In other words, adding parameter's does not care about the existing sql you have.

So, you could say do it this way:

Say, we have a search box for City, and then show only active.

So, we have this markup:

```
<font size="Large">Search for City:</font>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Text="Show only Active Hotels"
    style="margin-left:30px"  />

<asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="cmdSearch_Click"
    style="margin-left:20px"/>

<asp:Button ID="cmdClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" 
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="cmdClear_Click"
    style="margin-left:20px"/>

<br />
<br />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" Width="40%" GridLines="None"
    CssClass="table table-hover">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View"
                    OnClick="cmdView_Click" Height="32px" CssClass="btn" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, a simple text box (to search/limit by city), and a optional check box to only include Active Hotels, and then the search button

So, our code to load thus can be this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("", conn))
            {
                string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ";
                string strWhere = "";
                if (txtCity.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    strWhere = "(City like @City + '%')";
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
                }

                if (chkActive.Checked)
                {
                    if (strWhere.Length > 0) strWhere += " AND ";
                    strWhere += "(Active = 1)";
                }

                if (strWhere.Length > 0)
                    strSQL += " WHERE " + strWhere;

                strSQL += " ORDER BY HotelName";
                cmdSQL.CommandText= strSQL;
                Debug.Print(strSQL);    

                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

so, the result is now this:

[image]

Note how the code is written, that we can add 2 or 5 MORE optional search values.

If user leaves the "search" box blank, then we skip. Thus, the design can allow for "as many" extra searching criteria as you want.

So, you can "add more" or add up as many search box and critea on the fly.

We STILL NEVER concatenate user input into the sql, but STILL ALWAYS use parameter's.

So, we can now say even do this:

[image]

so for each new search option, you check if a value, and if yes, you add to the "str where", and ALSO add to the parameter's.

and the clear filter/search button thus becomes rather easy to code.

This:

```
    protected void cmdClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCity.Text = "";
        chkActive.Checked = false;  
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

So, be it a text box that is left empty, or a check box not checked? Well, we don't search for "empty" values, but just 100% ignore and not include that search criteria in the final sql.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer. But it will require me to use the direct query instead of the table adapter which is currently being used in the project for the all the data accesses. I faced a little bit similar situation in another page where i have to update the grade for specific semester and also for all the semester and i used the following query in the table adapter and when the value was null it would give me students from all semesters
SELECT personid, nametodisplay, departmentid, semesterid FROM dbo.vwAdminStudentsView
where semesterid = ISNULL( NULLIF(@sid, 0), semesterid )

Comment: Well, the issue is having 1 or even 5 optional parameter's and inputs. As the example shows, the above approach allows this. You can code parameter's to the dataset + adaptor,  but it's rather painful. So for advanced filtering that is "also" parameter safe, then the above approach works rather well. You could say use 2 conditions, and thus do this:  where ( (@City is null) or (City = @City)). NOTE VERY close, our condition is AGAINST the @City is null - not the column!!!).  So, that way, you can make parms optional with this idea.